# AES256 - 7zip Vs GPG

Tags: aes, gnupg, 7zip

I noticed that [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) provides an option to encrypt the contents of a folder using AES256 (Screenshot Below) and so does [GPG](https://www.gnupg.org/download/) using this command:

```
gpgtar --output <Name_Of_The_Output_File> -v --encrypt --symmetric --gpg-args "--cipher-algo AES256" <directory_to_encrypt>
```

Is there any difference between the two implementations? Is one more secure than the other?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7zip uses AES256 with the settings provided in that screenshot

GnuPG 2.1 [Defaults to AES-128](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86305/what-is-the-default-cipher-algorithm-for-gnupg) though it supports many many more

> 3DES, IDEA (since versions 1.4.13 and 2.0.20), CAST5, Blowfish, Twofish, AES-192, AES-256, Camellia-128, -192 and -256 (since versions 1.4.10 and 2.0.12) - [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard)

For the `gpgtar` command you provided it would use the same `AES-256` algorithm 7zip would use, the only real difference I could see is that one would use the `ustar` archive format and the `Zip` compression while the other would use `7z` archive format with `LZMA2` compression

> Compression service in PGP is provided using ZIP Algorithm. - [ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pgp-compression/)

Comment: Does that have any (known) security implications?

Comment: AES is not the interesting part. Everyone uses AES. Which AEAD mode (e.g. GCM, EAX)? Or which block cipher mode and which MAC and how are they combined, if not an AEAD mode (e.g. CTR-HMAC-SHA2, EtM)? Which PBKDF (e.g. scrypt)? Which settings for the KDF? etc. These are the details that matter. I personally recommend using https://github.com/FiloSottile/age

Comment: @7_R3X neither have known security issues at this time

Comment: It clear that [7zip uses AES in CBC mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/77548/18298). Do you know the mode of operation of gpgtar? It is not clear without the source code.